# htaccess is changing unescaping my uri

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

First off, I'm not sure that it's called escaping.

Basically I'm making a search page on my website. It works correctly without htaccess but once I add htaccess rewrite rules special characters are changed from escaped to regular characters.

Example.

Without htaccess

```
http://localhost:8888/search.php?s=hey%21%40%23%24
```

s variable returns `hey!@#$`

With htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?s=$1 [NC,L] 

http://localhost:8888/search/hey%21%40%23%24
```

s variable returns `hey!@` which tells me that # is commenting out the rest of the line.

How can I set it up so that it keeps special characters (!@#$) escaped in my htaccess file?

I understand that the URI is read/converted before any rules applied, so how can I reconvert it? or is this not possible?

Basically I just want my rewrite rules to use this uri `http://localhost:8888/search/hey%21%40%23%24`and for s to return `hey!@#$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`B` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b) to to escape non-alphanumeric characters before applying the transformation:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?s=$1 [NC,L,B,QSA]
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much; I know you're not supposed to say thanks, but honestly I've been stuck on this for a while now...

Comment: So I ran into a problem, if search string contains a / mark, the htaccess doesn't escape this character.

Comment: `/` is not escaped to `%2F` because `%2F` is prohibited by Apache (by default).